Get all combinations of a string in Python
Imagine that we have a string like: "good university student". We need to make all combinations of words in these string. We also need to add some separator characters in these combinations. For clarification please look at the example bellow:
    String: "good university student"
    Separators = ["-","+"]
    Expected results:
    student
    university
    good
    good-university-student
    good-university
    good-student
    university-student
    good+university+student
    good+university
    good+student
    university+student

I have tried the following code but the result is not what I'm expecting and I did not get all combinations.
def create_name_combos(mystring):
    words = mystring.split()
    combos = []
    for i in range(len(words) - 1):  
        for separator in ["-", "+", "&"]:
        current_combo = separator.join(words[:i+1] + [separator + words[i+1]])
        combos.append(current_combo)
    return combos

What would be the best solution to get all of possible combinations?

What’s wrong with the existing answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78738572/get-all-combinations-of-string-with-some-characters-between?

@Ry- I don't know, they just closed my question

You don’t know what’s wrong with the existing answers? Try them and find out?

@Ry- i checked all the answers, one of them does not provide all the combinations and the other one had errors.

You can use permutations and combinations from itertools:
import re
from itertools import permutations, chain, combinations


def create_name_combos(mystring):
    def gen(arr, separators):
        return set({re.sub(r' ', sep, s) for sep in separators for s in arr})

    def get_subsets(words):
        return chain.from_iterable(combinations(words, r) for r in range(1, len(words) + 1))

    words = mystring.split()
    combos = set()
    for subset in get_subsets(words):
        for perm in permutations(subset):
            combos.add(' '.join(perm))

    return sorted(gen(sorted(combos), ("+", '-', '')))


print(create_name_combos('good university student'))


Prints

['good', 'good+student', 'good+student+university', 'good+university',
'good+university+student', 'good-student', 'good-student-university',
'good-university', 'good-university-student', 'goodstudent',
'goodstudentuniversity', 'gooduniversity', 'gooduniversitystudent',
'student', 'student+good', 'student+good+university',
'student+university', 'student+university+good', 'student-good',
'student-good-university', 'student-university',
'student-university-good', 'studentgood', 'studentgooduniversity',
'studentuniversity', 'studentuniversitygood', 'university',
'university+good', 'university+good+student', 'university+student',
'university+student+good', 'university-good',
'university-good-student', 'university-student',
'university-student-good', 'universitygood', 'universitygoodstudent',
'universitystudent', 'universitystudentgood']


Is it possible to add some new combinations without any separator ? like "gooduniversitystudent"

@MahdiTalebi Try: sorted(gen(sorted(combos), ("+", '-', '')))

The requirement is for combinations - not permutations. So I'm not sure why this is the accepted answer

But it gives the other combinations which OP doesn't expect in the questions. ( I didn't downvote though)

@SuramuthuR Thanks! But, OP says it works. OP did not list all the output elements in the question.

Assuming that the order(sequence) does not matter:
String = "good university student"
str_lst = String.split() # Create a list of words in String
new_ls = [] # A new empty list
L = len(str_lst) # Declared length of str_lst.Just for convenience though not required

for i in range(L):
    new_ls.append(str_lst[i]) # append the single word 
    
    sub = str_lst[i+1:] # Create a substring of words with index > i
    for x in sub: # Iterate thru substring
        
        comb_2 = f'{str_lst[i]}+{x}' # combo joining with '+'
        comb_3 = f'{str_lst[i]}-{x}' # combo joining with '-'
        
        new_ls.append(comb_2) #append combo_1
        new_ls.append(comb_3) #append combo_2
print(new_ls) 

Output :
['good', 'good+university', 'good-university', 'good+student', 'good-student', 'university', 'university+student', 'university-student', 'student']

Instead of new_ls.append why not use new_ls.extend, and so on?

@toyotaSupra, Guess you're kidding. Line-7: if extend is used, it should be new_ls.extend([str_lst[i]]).  Line-12 should be comb_2 = [f'{str_lst[i]}+{x}']  and line-13 should be comb_3 = [f'{str_lst[i]}-{x}']. Why should we do that? i.e., Why to convert the elements into list and then use extend?

Because I followed by Python Convention.

@toyotaSupra,  Could you please give any link which suggests to use extend over append towards python convention. No offence, I just want to know.
